# Asp.net MVC 3 and NHibernate Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, architecture

I setup a solution with the following structure:

- Project.Core

  - Domain
  - Mappings
  - Repositories
- Project.Web

  - Views
  - Models
  - Contollers

Project.Web is the asp.net MVC 3 template.  I was wondering what would be the best architecture would be if i'm using MVC and NHibernate and I wont other web applications to utilize the Project.Core library.

It seems like the Domain and the Models are pretty much the same thing?

If I want to use the Domain's instead of the model how would I modify the asp.net mvc3 project to accept this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your domain objects in Project.Core are the same as your models. Just delete your Models folder in Project.Web and create a project reference from Project.Web to Project.Core. Since Project.Core is simply a Class Library project and contains your domain model, repositories, and mappings*, you can use these classes from Project.Web, a console app, web service, or any other code.

Comment: Thanks James.  I liked the recent presentation you gave on NHibernate 3.

Comment: in mvc, the Model should be the data context of the view, i don't think it should be mixed with the domain objects.

Comment: Yeah I prefer not to call this a model but instead a ViewModel or a PresentationModel which make the distinction between them and domain objets.

Comment: We can't use data annotations , eg [Required] if we place the models in project.core.Am I right? or can it be done?